# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'null' for key 'login.PRIMARY'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database

When I try to insert the data in database table it gives me error

```
"java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'null' for key 'login.PRIMARY'"
```

It duplicates the null column underneath the entered data. It gives me the  error on line "stmt.executeUpdate(sql);"

```
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %>   
<%@ page import = "javax.sql.*" %>  
    
<%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url       = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root";
    String user      = "root";
    String pass      = "root";
    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname  = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String email     = request.getParameter("email");
    String pass1     = request.getParameter("pass");
    
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    
    String sql = "INSERT INTO facebook.login (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES('"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','" +email+ "','" +pass1+ "');";

    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
%>
```

Comment: As a side note, you should use PreparedStatement so you don't need to do clumsy string concatenation.

Comment: You should definitely use PreparedStatements so as to avoid SQL Injection attacks such as [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Also (Microsoft) SQL Server is not the same thing as MySQL. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70538801/edit) your question to fix the tags.

Comment: debug the code by checking what the value is for string firstname,lastname,user, pass. As mentioned by others, use prepared statement period.

Comment: NO ONE should be storing plain-text passwords in a database.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's going on: there's a key in the database which is a string with the value `"null"` – it isn't a null value, it is instead a character sequence of four letters: "null". 99% certain that at one point `request.getParameter("email")` returned an actual null value back. Your insert statement constructs a string using whatever that result is, so it constructed the string `"null"` and inserted that into the database. At some other time later, `request.getParameter("email")` was again null, but the insert failed because of your primary key.

Comment: Maybe this helps someone, I debugged same error today `Duplicate entry 'NULL' for key ` it was because I exported from phpmyadmin and imported from command line, it worked OK after I exported + imported from command line

Answer (score 0):

You did not include a value in the insert statement the value for `login.PRIMARY` column  which happens to be a non duplicate column and it is possible that there's already a record with a null value for `login.PRIMARY` column that's why this error was encountered.

I suggest that you define a unique value for `login.PRIMARY` column in your `INSERT` statement or update your table structure for the `login.PRIMARY` to make it auto increment.

You can refer to below link on how to implement auto increment in a table.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: I tired to do what you suggested, however auto increment is not possible with VARCHAR. email's datatype is VARCHAR(45). I didn't creat table manually.

Comment: Better check the actual records present in facebook.login table and see if there's a record with null value on email. It also seems that the email value you're trying to insert using request.getParameter("email") is always null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to insert with duplicate (key already present in the table)primary key.

Your table might have accepted "null" as PK for one of the row , now again program trying to set null as PK which is already present in table.

You can use auto increment of PK if it's a number else in your case use PK on "email" bcz in real life scenario two email strings cannot be same.

Comment: Yes, my primary key is already set for email.

Comment: Did you checked that the PK you are inserting this time is not already present in the Table?

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me today while **exporting the .sql from phpMyAdmin and importing from command line**.

```
Duplicate entry 'NULL' for key my-table.my-column
```

Error was **gone after I exported from command line** and imported from command line.